# MariaDB thread_pool_size tuning

Tags: mariadb, performance, performance-tuning

I think the setting of **thread_pool_size = 500**  has been installed at my site with the wrong understanding of its application.

Our host server has only 40 CPUs.
Isn't this setting going to be counter-productive?

However, it looks to me like we might benefit from setting it slightly higher than our CPU count.

Am I correct in thinking that we should not set it (much) higher than our CPU count, and **never** higher than 128, the limit posed in the manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is going to be counterproductive. You can set it slightly higher than CPU count, maybe 2*CPU count, but not 12.5*CPU count. You do not want 500 connection to execute at the same time, CPU-bound. you only want to use as many  CPUs as you got.